# Dijkstra in Hadoop MapReduce - Selecting infinite distance

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, dijkstra

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/himank/Graph-Algorithm-MapReduce/blob/master/src/DijikstraAlgo.java) code in my virtual cluster environment. He defines lowest (infinite distance) as 125 since his input data set is pretty small.

But I am going to use big data sets such as [this](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/roadNet-PA.html) one. I thought I could just declare lowest as some number less than the Integer.MAX_VALUE but every "shortest path" results in Integer.MIN_VALUE in the end.

What am I missing here and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `Math.min()`

Try this solution [Math.max and Math.min outputting highest and lowest values allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772980/math-max-and-math-min-outputting-highest-and-lowest-values-allowed?rq=1)

OR

Just write a function to return minimum value.