# Optimal strategy to pair pairs of two given arrays, and win most of the comparisons

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am doing the following programming exercise: [Can you win the codewar?](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5e3f043faf934e0024a941d7). The statement is:

```
Two kingdoms are at war ⚔️ and, thanks to your codewarrior prowesses, you have been named general by one of the warring states. Your opponent's armies are larger than yours, but maybe you can reach a stalemate or even win the conflict if you are a good strategist.

You control the same number of armies as the rival state, but theirs are generally larger. You have to send a single army to fight each of your opponent's ones.
(It implies there will be as many battles as armies).
There are no possible David-and-Goliath surprises : the outcome of a battle is always the victory of the larger army (or a standoff if both are of the same size).
The winning side is the one which wins the most battles.
The outcome can be a stalemate if both win the same number.

You have to write a function

codewarResult(codewarrior, opponent)

that takes as input each side's armies as arrays of positive integers which represent their sizes. The function returns the strings "Defeat" , "Stalemate" or "Victory" depending on the outcome of the war for your side with an optimal strategy on your behalf.

For example, if you have 3 armies of sizes [1,4,1] and the rival state has armies of sizes [1,5,3] , despite you having on average smaller forces, it is possible to reach a stalemate :

1-1 : standoff
4-3 : victory for you
1-5 : victory for the opposing army

when the dust settles, you have won one battle, lost one, and one was indecisive so

codewarResult([1,4,1],[1,5,3])

should return "Stalemate".
More examples :

codewarResult([2,4,3,1],[4,5,1,2])

should return "Victory" because it is possible to win by disposing your amies this way :

2-1
4-4
3-2
1-5

thus winning two battles, deadlocking one and losing one.

codewarResult([1,2,2,1],[3,1,2,3])

should return "Defeat" because even with an optimal strategy it is not possible to win. The best you can do is one victory and one tie :

1-3
2-1
2-2
1-3
```

I have tried the following algorithm:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Kata {
  public static String codewarResult(int[] codewarrior, int[] opponent) {
    System.out.println("codewarrior: "+Arrays.toString(codewarrior));
    System.out.println("opponent: "+Arrays.toString(opponent));

    List<Integer> opponentMatchedIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int closestTo1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int indexInCodewarrior = 0;
    int indexInOpponent = 0;
    int score = 0;
    int battleResult = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < codewarrior.length; i++){
      closestTo1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      indexInCodewarrior = 0;
      indexInOpponent = 0;
      for(int j = 0; j < opponent.length; j++){
        battleResult = codewarrior[i]-opponent[j];
        if(!opponentMatchedIndexes.contains(j) && battleResult>closestTo1 && battleResult<=1){
          closestTo1 = battleResult;
          indexInCodewarrior = i;
          indexInOpponent = j;
        }
      }
      score+=closestTo1 < 0 ? -1 : closestTo1 == 0 ? 0 : 1;
      opponentMatchedIndexes.add(indexInOpponent);

      System.out.println("closesTo1: "+closestTo1);
      System.out.println("indexInCodewarrior: "+indexInCodewarrior);
      System.out.println("indexInOpponent: "+indexInOpponent);
      System.out.println("NumberInCodewarrior: "+codewarrior[indexInCodewarrior]);
      System.out.println("NumberInOpponent: "+opponent[indexInOpponent]);
      System.out.println("opponentMatchedIndexes: "+opponentMatchedIndexes);
      System.out.println("score: "+score);
    }

    return score<0?"Defeat":score==0?"Stalemate":"Victory";
  }
}
```

We have found a test where it outputs "Stalemate" when it should output "Victory":

```
@Test
public void testRandom() {
        int[] codewarrior = {2,5,1,4,1};
        int[] opponent =    {2,4,1,1,8};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codewarrior)+" vs "+Arrays.toString(opponent));
    assertEquals("Victory", Kata.codewarResult(codewarrior, opponent));
}
```

We have written what should do the code:

```
2-1 = 1 --> score = 1; 5-4 = 1 --> score = 2; 1-1 = 0 --> score = 2; 4-2 = 2 --> score = 3; 1-8 = -7 --> score = 2
```

And we have typed what is doing the code right now:

```
2-1 = 1 --> score = 1; 5-4 = 1 --> score = 2; 1-1 = 0 --> score = 2; 4-8 = -4 --> score = 1; 1-8=-7 --> score = 0
```

As you would notice at the 4th step it should do 4-2 = 2 --> score = 3; however it does 4-8=-4 --> score = 1.

We have spotted the line where we should change the code, and we have also thought what needs to be changed, however we struggle figuring out how exactly do we need to change it!

In particular we need to change the following line of code:

```
if(!opponentMatchedIndexes.contains(j) && battleResult>closestTo1 && battleResult<=1){
```

Because of battleResult<=1 is limiting our algorithm when it needs to take 4-2 = 2, and the explanation is that due to being battleResult = 2 > 1, it just skips out the instructions to save the number, inside the if.

In addition we have read:

[Math.max and Math.min outputting highest and lowest values allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772980/math-max-and-math-min-outputting-highest-and-lowest-values-allowed)
[get closest value to a number in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318733/get-closest-value-to-a-number-in-array)

Besides, how could we debug larger tests? I mean, the following tests also fails, however due to its bigger input arrays' size it is harder to figure out what is it happening:

```
@Test
public void testNumerousArmies() {
        int[] codewarrior = {2,1,3,1,1,3,3,2,3,1,1,1,3,1,3,1,3,3,1,2,3,3,1,3};
        int[] opponent =    {4,4,1,4,3,1,4,4,3,2,1,2,1,3,3,1,4,4,3,2,3,2,4,1};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codewarrior)+" vs "+Arrays.toString(opponent));
    assertEquals("Stalemate", Kata.codewarResult(codewarrior, opponent));
}
```

If you are curious the complete test suite is:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

// TODO: Replace examples and use TDD development by writing your own tests

public class SolutionTest {
    @Test
    public void testStalemate() {
            int[] codewarrior = {1,4,1};
            int[] opponent =    {1,5,3};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codewarrior)+" vs "+Arrays.toString(opponent));
        assertEquals("Stalemate", Kata.codewarResult(codewarrior, opponent));
    }

    @Test
    public void testVictory() {
            int[] codewarrior = {2,4,3,1};
            int[] opponent =    {4,5,1,2};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codewarrior)+" vs "+Arrays.toString(opponent));
        assertEquals("Victory", Kata.codewarResult(codewarrior, opponent));
    }

    @Test
    public void testDefeat() {
            int[] codewarrior = {1,2,2,1};
            int[] opponent =    {3,1,2,3};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codewarrior)+" vs "+Arrays.toString(opponent));
        assertEquals("Defeat", Kata.codewarResult(codewarrior, opponent));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEqualArmies() {
            int[] codewarrior = {1,1,1,1};
            int[] opponent =    {1,1,1,1};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codewarrior)+" vs "+Arrays.toString(opponent));
        assertEquals("Stalemate", Kata.codewarResult(codewarrior, opponent));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSingleArmy() {
            int[] codewarrior = {5};
            int[] opponent =    {6};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codewarrior)+" vs "+Arrays.toString(opponent));
        assertEquals("Defeat", Kata.codewarResult(codewarrior, opponent));
    }

    @Test
    public void testNumerousArmies() {
            int[] codewarrior = {2,1,3,1,1,3,3,2,3,1,1,1,3,1,3,1,3,3,1,2,3,3,1,3};
            int[] opponent =    {4,4,1,4,3,1,4,4,3,2,1,2,1,3,3,1,4,4,3,2,3,2,4,1};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codewarrior)+" vs "+Arrays.toString(opponent));
        assertEquals("Stalemate", Kata.codewarResult(codewarrior, opponent));
    }


    @Test
    public void testRandom() {
            int[] codewarrior = {2,5,1,4,1};
            int[] opponent =    {2,4,1,1,8};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codewarrior)+" vs "+Arrays.toString(opponent));
        assertEquals("Victory", Kata.codewarResult(codewarrior, opponent));
    }
}
```

How could we write an Optimal strategy to pair pairs of two given arrays, and win most of the comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to sort the array according battle strenght. Starting with the highest you compare.

1. If you cannot win the battle, you put the lowest strenght against it.
2. if it is a standoff. You now have 2 options. Make it a standoff, or loose the battle to win others. so now you are going deeper and test the results to see where you win most.

Example:

codewarChallenge([2,4,3,1],[4,5,1,2])

place them in order: ([1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,5])

4-5 you will loose so play 1-5. Now you have left ([2,3,4],[1,2,4])

4-4 standoff. two options 4-4 or 2-4.

when you play 4-4 you have left ([2,3],[1,2]), you will win both

when you play 2-4 you have left ([3,4],[1,2]), you will win both

so 4-4 is the better option.

You will need to go with a recursive pattern. Make a function what accepts both arrays and give as return value the score. 0 for loss, 1 for standoff and 2 for win. now recursively call the function when you encounter a standoff to get the rest of the score for both options. The highest score wins..

Comment: What would be the base case? One army agains only another one?

Comment: Yes, because it is recursive, the last call to the function will be with 2 arrays both one element. Note: You can also work with indexes (start and end) so you do not need to fill the arrays each time before you make the call tot eh function.

Answer (score 0):

I have been inspired by [Madjosz's exercise solution](https://www.codewars.com/kata/reviews/5e4b00cb77d51a0001da4125/groups/5e4b00cb77d51a0001da4129). (I saw it, wrote it has pseudocode in the notebook, and then tried to translate it into Java).

It shows how could we complete the exercise knowing that if we sort in ascending order, then we can recognize wins, and after that we should be able to detect draws. So then we just get the score.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Kata {

  public static String codewarResult/*⚔️️*/(int[] codewarrior, int[] opponent) {

    //We sort both arrays according to battle strenght, in ascending order
    int battles = codewarrior.length;
    Arrays.sort(codewarrior);
    System.out.println("sorted codewarrior: "+Arrays.toString(codewarrior));
    Arrays.sort(opponent);
    System.out.println("sorted opponent: "+Arrays.toString(opponent));
    boolean[] CWusedElements = new boolean[battles];
    boolean[] OPusedElements = new boolean[battles];
    int wins = 0;
    int draws = 0;

    //We detect when we win
    for(int i = 0; i < battles; i++){
      int found = -1;
      for(int j = 0; j < battles; j++){
        if (OPusedElements[j]) continue;
        if (opponent[j] < codewarrior[i]) {
          found = j;
        }
        else break;
      }
      if(found!=-1){
        wins++;
        CWusedElements[i] = OPusedElements[found] = true;
        System.out.println("codewarrior[i]: "+codewarrior[i]);
        System.out.println("Win! opponent[found]: "+opponent[found]);
      }
    }

    //We know when we draw
    for(int i = 0; i < battles; i++){
      if(CWusedElements[i]) continue;
      int found = -1;
      for(int j = 0; j < battles; j++){
        if(OPusedElements[j]) continue;
        if(opponent[j] == codewarrior[i]) {
          found = j;
        }
        else break;
      }
      if(found!=-1){
        draws++;
        CWusedElements[i] = OPusedElements[found] = true;
        System.out.println("codewarrior[i]: "+codewarrior[i]);
        System.out.println("Draw, opponent[found]: "+opponent[found]);
      }
    }  

    System.out.println("CWusedElements: "+Arrays.toString(CWusedElements));
    int defeats = battles-draws-wins;
    int score = wins-defeats;
    System.out.println("defeats: "+defeats);
    System.out.println("wins: "+wins);
    System.out.println("draws: "+draws);
    System.out.println("battles: "+battles);
    System.out.println("score: "+score);
    return score>0?"Victory":score==0?"Stalemate":"Defeat";
  }
}
```

If we test a stalemate, victory and defeat, as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

// TODO: Replace examples and use TDD development by writing your own tests

public class SolutionTest {
    @Test
    public void testStalemate() {
            int[] codewarrior = {1,4,1};
            int[] opponent =    {1,5,3};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codewarrior)+" vs "+Arrays.toString(opponent));
        assertEquals("Stalemate", Kata.codewarResult(codewarrior, opponent));
    }

    @Test
    public void testVictory() {
            int[] codewarrior = {2,4,3,1};
            int[] opponent =    {4,5,1,2};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codewarrior)+" vs "+Arrays.toString(opponent));
        assertEquals("Victory", Kata.codewarResult(codewarrior, opponent));
    }

    @Test
    public void testDefeat() {
            int[] codewarrior = {1,2,2,1};
            int[] opponent =    {3,1,2,3};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codewarrior)+" vs "+Arrays.toString(opponent));
        assertEquals("Defeat", Kata.codewarResult(codewarrior, opponent));
    }
}
```

The trace would be:

```
[1, 4, 1] vs [1, 5, 3]
sorted codewarrior: [1, 1, 4]
sorted opponent: [1, 3, 5]
codewarrior[i]: 4
Win! opponent[found]: 3
codewarrior[i]: 1
Draw, opponent[found]: 1
CWusedElements: [true, false, true]
defeats: 1
wins: 1
draws: 1
battles: 3
score: 0

[2, 4, 3, 1] vs [4, 5, 1, 2]
sorted codewarrior: [1, 2, 3, 4]
sorted opponent: [1, 2, 4, 5]
codewarrior[i]: 2
Win! opponent[found]: 1
codewarrior[i]: 3
Win! opponent[found]: 2
codewarrior[i]: 4
Draw, opponent[found]: 4
CWusedElements: [false, true, true, true]
defeats: 1
wins: 2
draws: 1
battles: 4
score: 1

[1, 2, 2, 1] vs [3, 1, 2, 3]
sorted codewarrior: [1, 1, 2, 2]
sorted opponent: [1, 2, 3, 3]
codewarrior[i]: 2
Win! opponent[found]: 1
codewarrior[i]: 2
Draw, opponent[found]: 2
CWusedElements: [false, false, true, true]
defeats: 2
wins: 1
draws: 1
battles: 4
score: -1
```